# What does it mean when a Python function is called in the format f(x)(y)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

In this [article](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate), the following line of code is given an an example:

```
 x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense_1")(inputs)
```

This appears to be a function call which first passes in 64, then two named arguments, then passes in `input`.

What's going on here?  Is `inputs` being passed to `layers.Dense` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically providing an argument for the function returned by another function (**wrapper function**), which also known as **inner function**:

```
def funcwrapper(y):
    def addone(x):
        return x + y + 1
    return addone

print(funcwrapper(3)(2))
```

Output:

```
6
```

Answer (score 8):

The function "Dense" returns something callable which gets called by the second pair of brackets.

For example:

```py
def function1():
    return function2

def function2():
    print('Function 2')

x = function1()
x() # This will print "Function 2"
```

It is also possible to return classes. In this case the brackets will call the constructor thus creating an instance of the class.

```py
def function1():
    return SomeClass

class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("__init__")

x = function1()
x() # This will print "__init__"
```

Comment: It's possible it doesn't return a function, but returns an instance of some other class.

Comment: Well... it returns something that's callable :)

Comment: Instead relying on `__init__()` you would typically define `__call__()` then in `function1` you would return an instance of the class.